# Pegar id do cliente clicado e gravar em uma variável para recuperar em uma modal

Tags: php, mysql, modal, while

Meu código PHP tem um *while* que lista os usuários cadastrados, a partir de uma consulta *MYSQL*.

Esta lista de usuários mostra a *foto*, o *id*, o *nome* e um *link* para abrir uma modal. Segue o código do *while*:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
  $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Não foi possível conectar servidor");
  $banco = mysql_select_db('rscc-db', $link) or die ("Impossível conectar banco de dados");
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id,nome,foto FROM tb_usuarios order by nome");
  while ($dadosUsu = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $id_usu = $dadosUsu['id'];
    $nome_usu = $dadosUsu['nome'];
    $foto_usu = $dadosUsu['foto'];
    echo "<img src='fotos/".$foto_usu."' alt='Foto de exibição'; width='25'; height='30'; align='left'; /><br />";
    echo $id_usu;
    echo $nome_usu;
    echo '<a href="#pagina" class="pagina click"> Info</a><br />';
  }
?>
```

Se clicarmos no link "Info" de qualquer um dos usuários listados, abrirá a janela modal. Segue o código *JavaScript* e a estrutura de *Divs* da modal:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        if($.cookie('modal') !== undefined){
            $('#modal').css('display','none');
        }
            $('.pagina').click(function(){
                 $('#modal').fadeIn(200);
            });
            $('.fechar, #modal').click(function(event){
                if(event.target !== this){
                    return;
                }
            $('#modal').fadeOut(200);
                $.cookie('modal', '1', { expires: 7 });
            });
        });
 </script>




<div id="modal">
    <div class="modal-box">
        <div class="modal-box-conteudo">

            <?php
                error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
                $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Não foi possível conectar servidor");
                $banco = mysql_select_db('rscc-db', $link) or die ("Impossível conectar banco de dados");
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id,nome,email,foto FROM tb_usuarios where id='**$id_usuario**'");

---- continuação do código -----

              ?>
        </div>
       <div class="fechar">X</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia armazenar na variável *id_usuario* o id do usuário que tiver sido clicado, para utilizar nesta consulta dentro da Modal.

Comment: Você só vai conseguir fazer isso via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar um atributo data ou até mesmo id no seu link recebendo a variável id e pegar ela pelo javascript e atribuir a algum campo input da sua modal.
Ex:

**PHP**

```
echo '<a href="#pagina" data-id="'.$id_usu.'" class="pagina click"> Info</a><br />';
```

**Js**

```
 $('.pagina').click(function(){
    # o $(this) é o objeto clicado, ou seja, o link e estou pegando o
    # conteúdo do campo data-id e atribuindo a um input dentro da sua modal
    $("#input-na-modal").val($($(this).attr("data-id"));

    $('#modal').fadeIn(200);
 });
```

Comment: Agradeço imensamente às contribuições. Na verdade, este modal aberto será apenas informativo, isto é, deverá apenas exibir informações gerais do usuário clicado no link. Ele não terá nenhum input. Ao invés de: $("#input-na-modal").val($($(this).attr("data-id")); como eu poderia pegar o ID do usuário, somente para utilizá-lo em uma consulta MYSQL ?